# How to pull commit to project after revert?

Tags: git

I have some problems with repo https://github.com/Kuba1618/Pac-Man_Game , I did push some commits on branch and now I wanna revert my chcnges to my commit. I tried switch to https://github.com/Kuba1618/Pac-Man_Game/commit/23fd4e9c5a08cb584e246204531391e09e92f433 commit and it actually works, but I don't know how to pull that commit to my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can change branch to `main`

`git checkout main`

Reset the branch to the commit you've mentioned

`git reset --hard 23fd4e9c5a08cb584e246204531391e09e92f433`

Then force push to github

`git push -f`

That should work.